# loop in tabular that uses \the\count to access current line number

Tags: tables, tex-core, counters, expansion, loops

I would like to generate an automatic table using loop. As suggested here before, it is best to first generate the lines in a toks and then pass them to tabular. However, I have problems with accessing the line counting variable inside the line as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcount\it
\newcount\tot

\newtoks\tablines
\def\addtomytablines#1{\tablines\expandafter{\the\tablines#1}}
\it=2
\tot=7
\loop
  \addtomytablines{\the\it&&&\\\cline{2-3}}
  \advance\it 1
\ifnum \it<\tot
\repeat

\def\maketable{%
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{7mm}|p{7mm}|p{5mm}} \cline{2-3}
    & foo & foo & \\ \cline{2-3}
    \the\tablines
    foofoo & & & \\ \cline{2-3}
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\maketable
\end{document}
```

The desired output would be that each line number starts with the current line number (so from 2 to 6), however the output is
[image: output]
so always writes the last value of \it.

Any ideas on what to change to make it work? Simply changing the line inside the loop to

```
  \addtomytablines\expandafter{\the\it&&&\\\cline{2-3}}
```

gives the correct numbers but not a table anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to expand the row number as far as you can before adding it to the `\tablines` token list. Here's one way of achieving that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{it}
\newcounter{tot}

\newtoks\tablines
\newcommand{\addtomytablines}[1]{\tablines\expandafter{\the\tablines#1}}
\setcounter{it}{2}
\setcounter{tot}{7}
\loop
  \expandafter\addtomytablines\expandafter{\number\arabic{it} & & & \\ \cline{2-3}}
  \stepcounter{it}
\ifnum \value{it}<\value{tot}
\repeat

\def\maketable{%
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{7mm}|p{7mm}|p{5mm}}
    \cline{2-3}
    & foo & foo & \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \the\tablines
    foofoo & & & \\
    \cline{2-3}
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\maketable
\end{document}
```

`\expandafter` the `\number` of `\arabic{it}` (LaTeX counter usage) expands the value of the `it` counter before passing it to `\addtomytablines`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works fine, even when changing the counters back to counts...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two counters, one inside the `\addtomytablines` command, and one for the main loop. (I don't fully understand why.)

I took the liberty of cleaning up your code and writing it in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\tablines
\def\addtomytablines#1{\tablines\expandafter{\the\tablines#1}}

\newcounter{row}
\newcounter{loop}
\newcounter{maxrow}

\setcounter{row}{2}
\setcounter{loop}{\value{row}}
\setcounter{maxrow}{7}

\loop
    \addtomytablines{%
        \therow & & & \\%
        \cline{2-3}%
        \stepcounter{row}
    }
    \stepcounter{loop}%
\ifnum\value{loop} < \value{maxrow}
\repeat

\def\maketable{%
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{7mm}|p{7mm}|p{5mm}} 
    \cline{2-3}
    & foo & foo & \\ \cline{2-3}
    \the\tablines
    foofoo & & & \\ \cline{2-3}
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\maketable
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to avoid LaTeX, only TeX, as mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: If you want to use the Plain TeX format then you can't use `\documentclass` or `tabular` and you should use `\newcount\it` (still would be good to use unambiguous variable names) and `\advance\it by 1`.

Comment: The algorithm is exactly the same, just different syntax in Plain TeX. `\newcount\row \row=2 \advance\row by 1` vs. `\newcounter{row} \setcounter{row}{2} \stepcounter{row}`.

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Got it now. The other solutions seems to need only one counter though.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX kernel has some non publicized programming tools, such as while loops. The more well-know `\loop` is not appropriate here inside the tabular for a number of reasons, one being that it makes a local definition which will get lost, the other one is that `\cline` also uses `\loop` and this would clash.

Here is a one-liner to get user access to one LaTeX while loop.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\newcounter{index}

\makeatletter
   \def\WHILENUM #1{\@whilesw\ifnum#1\relax\fi}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{7mm}|p{7mm}|p{5mm}} 
\cline{2-3}
    & foo & foo & \\ 
\cline{2-3}
\setcounter{index}{2}%
\WHILENUM 
 {\value{index}<7}
 {\theindex\stepcounter{index}&&&\\\cline{2-3}}%
    foofoo & & & \\ 
\cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]